# Jquery display: nome

Tags: jquery

Estou precisando colocar um `display: nome` para bloquear a classe logo, mas, do jeito que fiz, não está funcionando. Consegui colocar um `opacity:0` mas o display não pegou.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".logo").animate({display: 'nome'}, 0);
});
```

Comment: `'nome' != 'none'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O erro é de digitação e de uso.

**Substitua por:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.logo').css('display', 'none');

    });
</script>
```

O método `jQuery.fn.animate` não funciona para a propriedade `display` pois ela não existe nos hooks de `step`. E você colocou "nome" ao envés de `none`.

Você pode criar uma transição para que o elemento desapareça usando `jQuery.fn.fadeOut` desta forma:

```
$('.logo').fadeOut(400);
```

Sendo que 400 é a duração do efeito.

Para fazer aparecer basta usar `jQuery.fn.fadeIn` da mesma forma.

Creio que isso já resolva.

Comment: Ok pegou perfeitamente, mas como uso um duration ai ? que é tipo o transition se é que você me entenda

Comment: Ao envés de duration você precisa de uma animação que faça o efeito de transição e no final dê display none, você pode verificar isso manualmente, mas o jQuery tem algumas funções prontas. Você pode usar nesse caso `$('.logo').fadeOut(400);` sendo que essa função faz desaparecer e 400 é a duração (Para aparecer use "fadeIn").

Comment: Entendi vlw diego =D

Comment: @brasofilo farei isso, obrigado.

Answer (score 6):

Você não poderá animar a propriedade display. Antes de alterar para display `none` (que você escreveu errado), você deve animar uma outra propriedade qualquer que faça o elemento sumir:

- `width` ou `height`: animar até 0;
- `opacity`: animar até a transparência total (note que isso vai causar um efeito meio indesejável, pois o espaço continuará ocupado durante a animação)

Ai depois dessas animações, você poderá settar o display none.

Exemplo:

```
$('.logo').animate({
     width: 0
   },
   {
     duration: 5000,
     complete: function(){
        $('.logo').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Entendi miguel =D